# Display more than one object from array on Angular Update CRUD Form

Tags: arrays, angular, crud, angular-reactive-forms

I am currently able to edit all data from my update CRUD form except for the dynamic nested array (called 'mitigations') that only returns the first object on my form. I have 4 objects, but it's only showing 1 out of 4, and I want the end user to be able to edit all of them through the same form they originally created.  I also want them to be able to add new mitigations or remove existing ones as they can with the create CRUD form.

Please let me know what I'm missing. Thanks.

**edit.component.ts**

```js
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {

  getId: any;
  updateForm: FormGroup;
  
  constructor(
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private crudService: CrudService
  ) {
    this.getId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.crudService.GetRisk(this.getId).subscribe(res => {
      this.updateForm.setValue({ 
       ...
        mitigations: res['mitigations']
      });
    });

    this.updateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      ...
      mitigations: this.formBuilder.array([])
    })
  }
  

  addMitigation() {
    let control = <FormArray>this.updateForm.controls.mitigations;
    control.push(
      this.formBuilder.group({
        mitigation_description: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,  Validators.minLength(10)])],
        mitigation_option: ['', Validators.required]
      })
    )
  }

  removeMitigation(index) {
    let control = <FormArray>this.updateForm.controls.mitigations;
    control.removeAt(index)
  }

  ngOnInit() { 
    let control = <FormArray>this.updateForm.controls.mitigations;
    control.push(
      this.formBuilder.group({
        mitigation_description: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,  Validators.minLength(10)])],
        mitigation_option: ['', Validators.required]
      })
    )
  }

  onUpdate(): any {
    this.crudService.updateRisk(this.getId, this.updateForm.value)
    .subscribe(() => {
        console.log('Data updated successfully!')
        this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/risk/details'))
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }

}
```

**edit.component.html**

```html
<div class="card-body widget-body">
            <form [formGroup]="updateForm" (ngSubmit)="onUpdate()">
              <div formArrayName="mitigations">
                <div *ngFor="let mitigation of updateForm.get('mitigations')['controls']; let i=index">
                  <div [formGroupName]="i">
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                      <label for="textarea">Mitigation {{i+1}} Description</label>
                      <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm checking-field" formControlName="mitigation_description" required></textarea>    
                      <span class="help-block" *ngIf="mitigation.get('mitigation_description').touched">
                        <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="mitigation.get('mitigation_description').hasError('required')">Description is required</span>
                        <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="mitigation.get('mitigation_description').hasError('minlength')">Minimum of 10 characters</span>
                      </span> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="select">Mitigation {{i+1}} Option</label>
                      <select class="form-control form-control-sm checking-field" formControlName="mitigation_option">
                        <option>Accept</option>
                        <option>Transfer</option>
                        <option>Reduce</option>
                        <option>Avoid</option>
                      </select>
                      <span class="help-block text-danger" *ngIf="mitigation.get('mitigation_option').touched && mitigation.get('mitigation_option').hasError('required')">Option is required</span>                     
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn-sm btn-main" (click)="addMitigation()">Add Mitigation</button>
                    <button [hidden]="i == 0" type="button" class="btn-sm btn-danger pull-right" (click)="removeMitigation(i)">Remove Mitigation {{i+1}}</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with the help of a developer.  This is what the working constructor looks like:

```js
constructor(
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private crudService: CrudService
  ) {
    this.getId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.crudService.GetRisk(this.getId).subscribe(res => {
    const mitigations = this.updateForm.get('mitigations') as FormArray;
    while (mitigations.length) {
    mitigations.removeAt(0);
    }

    this.updateForm.patchValue(res);

    res.mitigations.forEach(mitigation =>       
    mitigations.push(this.formBuilder.group(mitigation)));
      this.updateForm.setValue({ 
        ...
        mitigations: res['mitigations']
      });
    });

    this.updateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      ...
      mitigations: this.formBuilder.array([])
    })
  }
```